# JSF PrimeFaces paginate DataTable on server-side

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

What I'm trying to do is filling DataTable with a paginated response body. Is it possible to call a page of response body on a specific DataTable page?

***For instance:***

When I head to page 3, it should be filled with the below request's response
http://localhost:8090/relationsByApplication/1?page=3

**`Repository`**

```
public interface MemberRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MemberModel, String>{
        public Page<MemberModel> findByApplicationId(long applicationId, Pageable page);}
```

**`Service`**

```
public List<MemberModel> getRelationsByApplicationId (long applicationId,Pageable page) {
    return memberRepository.findByApplicationId(applicationId,page).getContent();}
```

**`Controller`**

```
@RequestMapping("/relationsByApplication/{id}")
    public List<MemberModel> getRelationsByApplicationId(@PathVariable long id, Pageable page) {
        return memberService.getRelationsByApplicationId(id, page);}
```

I assigned response of (http://localhost:8090/relationsByApplication/1) to `relations` List yet DataTable only shows 1 page/20 elements which response's first page has.

How can I achieve to fill that DataTable according to it's page number and filtering a column on whole pages not only the selected one?

**xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable id="relationTable" var="rel" value="#{index.relations}"
                    widgetVar="relTable" rows="20" paginator="true"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                            emptyMessage="No relation found with given criteria"
                    filteredValue="#{index.filteredRelations}" resizableColumns="true"
                    draggableColumns="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300">

                    <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:200px;"
                        filterBy="#{rel.name}"
                        sortBy="#{rel.name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{rel.name}" />
                    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml . What i see is is a requirement for implementation of  LazyDataModel with override of  public List load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters)

Comment: Sure, I assigned response's content to datasource yet DataTable is loaded with just first page of response.

Comment: Your controller, service and repository classes are managed by spring, so I guess they are not part of your problem here. If the API provides paging, you've got two choices: 1. Load all the relations from your managed bean and keep them stored here (you have to change nothing, but performance could be poor). 2. Go with @Ravi's recommendation and implement a lazy data model (it might be a lot of work to do, depending on the table).

Comment: Thanks for all help. Overriding load method works. **`String URI = getUrl() + "?page=" + first/pageSize + "&size=" + pageSize;`**